# AngularJS unit testing directive with ngModel

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I have made a directive which uses ngModel:

```
.directive('datetimepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['datetimepicker', '?^ngModel'],
        controller: 'DateTimePickerController',
        replace: true,

        templateUrl: ...,

        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controllers) {
            var pickerController = controllers[0];
            var modelController = controllers[1];

            if (modelController) {
                pickerController.init(modelController);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But when testing...

```
var scope, element;

beforeEach(module('appDateTimePicker'));
beforeEach(module('templates'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    compile = $compile;
    scope = $rootScope;

    scope.model = new Date();

    element = compile(angular.element('<datetimepicker ng-model="model"></datetimepicker>'))(scope);

    scope.$digest();
}));
```

I can't anyhow set value to ng-model.

Fo example, here scope.model is a date, so scope.year and scope.month should be date and year of that model, but it is undefined.

As seen in the directive's code, I'm using this.init on the controller to initialise all the process.

What am I missing?

### EDIT

Example of test:

```
it('should test', function () {
    expect(scope.model).toBe(undefined);
    expect(scope.year).toBe(undefined);
});
```

### EDIT

This helped to solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pTv49/3/

Comment: It might help to see how you are setting up your tests. Show an it() block.

Comment: Not testing anything as my scope isn't changing. But added one test above.

Answer (score 3):

The `'?^ngModel'` mean you are asking for the `ng-model` on parent elements, but the html in your test has the `ng-model` on the same element as `datetimepicker` directive.

If the `ng-model` really have to be on parent elements, you have to change the html in the test, for example:

```
element = compile(angular.element('<div ng-model="model"><datetimepicker></datetimepicker></div>'))(scope);
```

But if it should be on the same element, just remove the `^` symbol in the `require:`

```
require: ['datetimepicker', '?ngModel'],
```

Comment: No, still the same. No I tested it like that - I described a variable $scope.test = "value" inside directive's controller. Strangely when I test it, it is still undefined. I can't seem to access scope of the controller...

Answer (score 0):

The directive has a `scope: {}` block so it creates an isolate scope. I assume, in the tests `scope` refers to the outer scope, while `element.isolateScope()` should be used to reference the inner scope instead.

Comment: Why downvoted? The final fiddle provided by topic starter uses isolateScope(), so my suggestion was correct.